# The most popular Resolutions and Aspect Ratios in Android OS 2019

Tags: libgdx, android, textures, screen, aspect-ratio

I develop the game with Libgdx framework. When I tried to deal with support multiple screen resolutions it turns out that Libgdx is not following Android approach how to deal with Screen sizes and densities (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc folders).

I found only one way to handle assets - [ResolutionFileResolver](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/ResolutionFileResolver.html).
I have to create folders with different resolutions and the Libgdx choose more appropriate texture for me automatically for each device.

Android platform has a huge amount of Phones and Tables with different screen resolutions. I have to find a good strategy on how to handle it.

For example let's take a look at the case where I have 2 folders in my game: "800x480" and "1440x2560". The device on which I run the game has "1280x720". In this case, "800x480" resolution will be chosen as more appropriate. It leads to bad quality of the Textures because of stretching.
At the same time, I can't leave only one asset with high quality. It leads to cut all older devices with a small amount of RAM.

The idea is to create 3 most popular resolutions for 3 categories: 
low, middle and high resolutions.

1. **Where can I find some statistic about the resolutions popularity of Android Devices?** I know about the [Android Developer Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/) but it doesn't show Screen Resolutions.
2. Does anyone use Libgdx in 2019? How to deal with Multiple Screen Support in this framework?
3. Any *real* statistic about the most popular Aspect Ratio? Which aspect ratio you choose as "basic" in your games?

I would love to see any "best practice" how to cover as many devices as possible with the good quality of the view.